# Decidable product with an undecidable projection

Tags: computability

I got some problems with building a set, which should looks like this: $S = A\times B \subset N \times N $, where $S$ is decidable but $A$ is undecidable.

Could somebody give me a clue how to actually do this?

Comment: Could you double-check your question? It asks for $S$ to be a product $A \times B$, but that doesn't seem to match either the title or the accepted answer. Did you mean instead that $S$ should be a subset of $\mathbb{N}^2$ such that the first projection is an undecidable set, but $S$ is decidable? That would be a more interesting question.

Comment: That's exactly you're talking about. The thing is that we should build a set $S=A \times B$ so that it's a decidable one, but its first projection is undecidable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be set of Turing machines that halt, which is clearly undecidable. Now $B$ needs to be something that helps you decide $A$ (a certificate if you will, in the sense of a certificate for a $NP$ problem). Hint: if a TM halts, it halts in a finite number of steps.

Comment: Alternatively, $B$ can be any non-empty subset of $N$. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer
Do you mean that we can trivially enumerate the machines and $B$ will consists of these numbers?

Comment: @RickyDemer Actually, that doesn't work. $B$ must be *infinite* or if $A \times B$ were decidable and $B$ were finite we could decide $A$ by enumerating over all $b \in B$. But I agree $B$ can be any arbitrary infinite subset of $N$ though.

Comment: For all elements $b_0$ of $B$, for all elements $a$ of $A$, $\;\;\;\; \langle a,b_0\rangle \: \in \: S \;\; \iff \;\; \langle a,b_0\rangle \: \in \: A\times B \;\; \iff \;\; a\in A \;\;\;\;\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting at with $B$. If there was a $B$ that “helps you decide $A$”, it means you've found a way to decide $A$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $A$ is undecidable. @RickyDemer Didn't you mean “$B$ can be any empty subset of $N$”? If $b \in B$ then as you say for any deciding $x \in A$ (undecidable by assumption) is equivalent to deciding $(x,b) \in S$ (decidable by assumption).

Comment: Ah, was your answer supposed to construct $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}^2$ such that the first projection of $S$ is $A$? That would be a more interesting question, and it's what the title implies, but it's not what the body of the question asks for, at least now (it may have been a misuse of notation though).

Comment: Yes. I think that it is an issue of notation, because as it is currently formulated the problem is unsolvable. Before David edited the problem it read "$<A,B>\subset N\times N$" - which isn't very common notation either, but the projection interpretation is the only one that makes sense. Also see the Arteom's self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let $B \subset N^{2}$. Also we know that exist a set, which is enumerable but undecidable (for example, a set of all $n$ so that $U(n, n)$ is defined). This way, we build a $X \times Y$, which is decidable. More precisely, $(x, y) \in X \times Y$ iff $U(x, x)$ stops in $y$ steps. So $X \times Y$  is decidable, but its first projection (a set of $x$ so that $U(x, x)$ is defined) not.